# How to install and deploy a nodejs site on local webserver?

Tags: node.js

title - installing and running nodejs site locally

Somebody please help me on how to install and build this website and run it locally on my PC . I have downloaded and unzipped it .

https://github.com/vaalentin/2015

Installed node js.
1."npm install" it did not go well
What to do ???

```
F:\2015-master\2015-master>npm install
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No description
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No license field.
npm WARN prefer global npm@2.10.1 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\gulp-jsh
de_modules\jshint requires lodash@'3.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\gulp-jsh
de_modules\lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.9.1
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\gulp-jsh
de_modules\rcloader requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\gulp-jsh
de_modules\lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.9.1
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\watchify
modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\through2 require
able-stream@'~1.0.17' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\2015-master\2015-master\node_modules\watchify
modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13
```

After this i typed npm install -g in nodejs command prompt . Following error occurred ...

```
F:\2015-master\2015-master>npm install -g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install F:\2015-master\2015-master
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\2015-master\2015-master\npm-debug.log

F:\2015-master\2015-master>
```

Kindly help me on how to resolve this . @slebetman @michael-blankenship

P.S When I tried in my laptop I finished npm install step .
In next step I typed gulp build .

Then HTML Success , Scripts 2D Success , Scripts 3D Success , ...

After that it stopped Nothing happened .

Comment: You need to install node.js in order to install npm. First, because npm is written in node.js. Second because npm comes with node.js so if you install node.js npm will automatically be installed with it. To install node.js read the instructions form their website (or the github repo)

Comment: ["npm install" it did not go well]  Elaborating might help.  "npm install" might say a variety of things.  If this is your first time attempting to run npm on a Windows PC you might need to go into your PATH environment variable and add the location of some of the executables.  For me on Windows 8 that was:  Start -> Search -> "environment" -> Edit the system environment variables -> Environment Variables... -> System Variables -> Path -> Edit... -> [C:\Ruby193\bin;c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;]  Those are some of the ones I've added.

Comment: @slebetman    I have updated this issue above. Kindly look into it and help me resolve this.I have been trying to run this for about a month.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship I have updated the issue . Kindly help me resolve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm attempting to install it myself and document the process.  I have an N: drive mapped to my Node.js folder area so that paths aren't so deep on Microsoft Windows.

```
n:
cd \
git clone https://github.com/vaalentin/2015.git 2015-master
```

Response:

```
Cloning into '2015-master'...
remote: Counting objects: 807, done.
remote: Total 807 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 807
Receiving objects: 100% (807/807), 74.64 MiB | 1.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (334/334), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (248/248), done.
```

Next:

```
cd 2015-master
npm install
```

Response:

```
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No description
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No repository field.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\85fb810a-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\85fb810a-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd N:\2015-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\85fb810a-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

You may safely ignore the first errors since they're warning of fields that aren't in the package.json file.  The next error suggests there's a locking file in place in my local node install.

```
c:
cd \users\me\appdata\roaming\npm-cache
dir *.lock /s
```

Response:

```
Volume in drive C is Windows
Volume Serial Number is E0A6-BC0C
File Not Found
```

Whatever npm locking error existed during the npm install step, this was caused by the collection of file dependencies in the 2015 program's package.json file.

```
n:
cd \2015-master
npm install
```

Response:

```
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No description
npm WARN package.json 2015@ No repository field.
gulp-util@3.0.4 node_modules\gulp-util
├── array-differ@1.0.0
├── array-uniq@1.0.2
├── object-assign@2.0.0
├── lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0
├── beeper@1.0.0
├── lodash._reescape@3.0.0
├── lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0
├── replace-ext@0.0.1
├── minimist@1.1.1
├── vinyl@0.4.6 (clone-stats@0.0.1, clone@0.2.0)
├── lodash.template@3.6.1 (lodash._basecopy@3.0.1, lodash.escape@3.0.0, lodash.restparam@3.6.1, lodash.templatesettings@3.1.0, lodash._basetostring@3.0.0, lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.8, lodash._basevalues@3.0.0, lodash.keys@3.1.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (ansi-styles@2.0.1, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.0, readable-stream@1.0.33)
├── multipipe@0.1.2 (duplexer2@0.0.2)
└── dateformat@1.0.11 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
```

And it looks like it may now be happy just by running npm install a second time.  Given the absence of a useful README.md file in this project I'm at a loss as to how to use it.  Ignore the errors you got and do a second "npm install" in your project directory.